# Filling two overlapping areas in d3.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am drawing two lines overlapping (sometimes the first one is higher, and sometimes the second one has higher value on y axis) each other in d3.js. I want to fill the areas under the lines in such a way that:

- The area under the lower one will be gray.
- The area between the two lines will be either green or red. If the first line has higher value, it will be green and if the second has higher value, it will be red.

[For example](https://pbs.twimg.com/media/DBOir97XoAAvigp.jpg)

For now I only have this:

```
var area = d3.area()
            .curve(d3.curveBasis)
            .x(function(d) { return margin.left + x(d.date); })
            .y0(margin.top + height)
            .y1(function(d) { return y(d.value); });
```

But this does not work, of course. I know about stacked area charts but I think I need some tricks to make this work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it overlapping 2 areas:

```
// a gray area which finish in the minimun data
var greyArea = d3.svg.area()
    .interpolate("basis")
    .x(function(d) { return x(d.date); })
    .y(function(d) { return y(Math.min(d["First Line"], d["Second Line"])); });

// a colored area which in the value of the first line
var coloredArea = d3.svg.area()
    .interpolate("basis")
    .x(function(d) { return x(d.date); })
    .y1(function(d) { return y(d["First Line"]); });
```

then draw them with,

```
svg.append("clipPath")
  .attr("id", "clip-above")
  .append("path")
  .attr("d", coloredArea.y0(height));

svg.append("clipPath")
  .attr("id", "clip-below")
  .append("path")
  .attr("d", coloredArea.y0(0));

svg.append("path")
  .attr("class", "area below")
  .attr("clip-path", "url(#clip-below)")
  .attr("d", coloredArea.y0(function(d) { return y(d["Second Line"]); }));

svg.append("path")
  .attr("class", "area above")
  .attr("clip-path", "url(#clip-above)")
  .attr("d", coloredArea);

svg.append("path")
  .attr("class", "area gray")
  .attr("d", greyArea.y0(height));
```

**Working demo** [JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davcs86/ot19Lyt8/207/)

```js
var data = [{"date":"20111001","First Line":"63.4","Second Line":"62.7"},{"date":"20111002","First Line":"58.0","Second Line":"59.9"},{"date":"20111003","First Line":"53.3","Second Line":"59.1"},{"date":"20111004","First Line":"55.7","Second Line":"58.8"},{"date":"20111005","First Line":"64.2","Second Line":"58.7"},{"date":"20111006","First Line":"58.8","Second Line":"57.0"},{"date":"20111007","First Line":"57.9","Second Line":"56.7"},{"date":"20111008","First Line":"61.8","Second Line":"56.8"},{"date":"20111009","First Line":"69.3","Second Line":"56.7"},{"date":"20111010","First Line":"71.2","Second Line":"60.1"},{"date":"20111011","First Line":"68.7","Second Line":"61.1"},{"date":"20111012","First Line":"61.8","Second Line":"61.5"},{"date":"20111013","First Line":"63.0","Second Line":"64.3"},{"date":"20111014","First Line":"66.9","Second Line":"67.1"},{"date":"20111015","First Line":"61.7","Second Line":"64.6"},{"date":"20111016","First Line":"61.8","Second Line":"61.6"},{"date":"20111017","First Line":"62.8","Second Line":"61.1"},{"date":"20111018","First Line":"60.8","Second Line":"59.2"},{"date":"20111019","First Line":"62.1","Second Line":"58.9"},{"date":"20111020","First Line":"65.1","Second Line":"57.2"},{"date":"20111021","First Line":"55.6","Second Line":"56.4"},{"date":"20111022","First Line":"54.4","Second Line":"60.7"},{"date":"20111023","First Line":"54.4","Second Line":"65.1"},{"date":"20111024","First Line":"54.8","Second Line":"60.9"},{"date":"20111025","First Line":"57.9","Second Line":"56.1"},{"date":"20111026","First Line":"54.6","Second Line":"54.6"},{"date":"20111027","First Line":"54.4","Second Line":"56.1"},{"date":"20111028","First Line":"42.5","Second Line":"58.1"},{"date":"20111029","First Line":"40.9","Second Line":"57.5"},{"date":"20111030","First Line":"38.6","Second Line":"57.7"},{"date":"20111031","First Line":"44.2","Second Line":"55.1"},{"date":"20111101","First Line":"49.6","Second Line":"57.9"},{"date":"20111102","First Line":"47.2","Second Line":"64.6"},{"date":"20111103","First Line":"50.1","Second Line":"56.2"},{"date":"20111104","First Line":"50.1","Second Line":"50.5"},{"date":"20111105","First Line":"43.5","Second Line":"51.3"},{"date":"20111106","First Line":"43.8","Second Line":"52.6"},{"date":"20111107","First Line":"48.9","Second Line":"51.4"},{"date":"20111108","First Line":"55.5","Second Line":"50.6"},{"date":"20111109","First Line":"53.7","Second Line":"54.6"},{"date":"20111110","First Line":"57.7","Second Line":"55.6"},{"date":"20111111","First Line":"48.5","Second Line":"53.9"},{"date":"20111112","First Line":"46.8","Second Line":"54.0"},{"date":"20111113","First Line":"51.1","Second Line":"53.8"},{"date":"20111114","First Line":"56.8","Second Line":"53.5"},{"date":"20111115","First Line":"59.7","Second Line":"53.4"},{"date":"20111116","First Line":"56.5","Second Line":"52.2"},{"date":"20111117","First Line":"49.6","Second Line":"52.7"},{"date":"20111118","First Line":"41.5","Second Line":"53.1"},{"date":"20111119","First Line":"44.3","Second Line":"49.0"},{"date":"20111120","First Line":"54.0","Second Line":"50.4"},{"date":"20111121","First Line":"54.1","Second Line":"51.1"},{"date":"20111122","First Line":"49.4","Second Line":"52.3"},{"date":"20111123","First Line":"50.0","Second Line":"54.6"},{"date":"20111124","First Line":"44.0","Second Line":"55.1"},{"date":"20111125","First Line":"50.3","Second Line":"51.5"},{"date":"20111126","First Line":"52.1","Second Line":"53.6"},{"date":"20111127","First Line":"49.6","Second Line":"52.3"},{"date":"20111128","First Line":"57.2","Second Line":"51.0"},{"date":"20111129","First Line":"59.1","Second Line":"49.5"},{"date":"20111130","First Line":"50.6","Second Line":"49.8"},{"date":"20111201","First Line":"44.3","Second Line":"60.4"},{"date":"20111202","First Line":"43.9","Second Line":"62.2"},{"date":"20111203","First Line":"42.1","Second Line":"58.3"},{"date":"20111204","First Line":"43.9","Second Line":"52.7"},{"date":"20111205","First Line":"50.2","Second Line":"51.5"},{"date":"20111206","First Line":"54.2","Second Line":"49.9"},{"date":"20111207","First Line":"54.6","Second Line":"48.6"},{"date":"20111208","First Line":"43.4","Second Line":"46.4"},{"date":"20111209","First Line":"42.2","Second Line":"49.8"},{"date":"20111210","First Line":"45.0","Second Line":"52.1"},{"date":"20111211","First Line":"33.8","Second Line":"48.8"},{"date":"20111212","First Line":"36.8","Second Line":"47.4"},{"date":"20111213","First Line":"38.6","Second Line":"47.2"},{"date":"20111214","First Line":"41.9","Second Line":"46.1"},{"date":"20111215","First Line":"49.6","Second Line":"48.8"},{"date":"20111216","First Line":"50.2","Second Line":"47.9"},{"date":"20111217","First Line":"40.6","Second Line":"49.8"},{"date":"20111218","First Line":"29.1","Second Line":"49.1"},{"date":"20111219","First Line":"33.7","Second Line":"48.3"},{"date":"20111220","First Line":"45.8","Second Line":"49.3"},{"date":"20111221","First Line":"47.4","Second Line":"48.4"},{"date":"20111222","First Line":"54.4","Second Line":"53.3"},{"date":"20111223","First Line":"47.8","Second Line":"47.5"},{"date":"20111224","First Line":"34.9","Second Line":"47.9"},{"date":"20111225","First Line":"35.9","Second Line":"48.9"},{"date":"20111226","First Line":"43.6","Second Line":"45.9"},{"date":"20111227","First Line":"42.9","Second Line":"47.2"},{"date":"20111228","First Line":"46.2","Second Line":"48.9"},{"date":"20111229","First Line":"30.8","Second Line":"50.9"},{"date":"20111230","First Line":"40.8","Second Line":"52.9"},{"date":"20111231","First Line":"49.8","Second Line":"50.1"},{"date":"20120101","First Line":"46.3","Second Line":"53.9"},{"date":"20120102","First Line":"43.2","Second Line":"53.1"},{"date":"20120103","First Line":"30.3","Second Line":"49.7"},{"date":"20120104","First Line":"19.2","Second Line":"52.7"},{"date":"20120105","First Line":"32.1","Second Line":"52.6"},{"date":"20120106","First Line":"41.2","Second Line":"49.0"},{"date":"20120107","First Line":"47.0","Second Line":"51.0"},{"date":"20120108","First Line":"46.0","Second Line":"56.8"},{"date":"20120109","First Line":"34.7","Second Line":"52.3"},{"date":"20120110","First Line":"39.4","Second Line":"51.6"},{"date":"20120111","First Line":"40.4","Second Line":"49.8"},{"date":"20120112","First Line":"45.4","Second Line":"51.9"},{"date":"20120113","First Line":"40.7","Second Line":"53.7"},{"date":"20120114","First Line":"30.4","Second Line":"52.9"},{"date":"20120115","First Line":"23.9","Second Line":"49.7"},{"date":"20120116","First Line":"22.6","Second Line":"45.3"},{"date":"20120117","First Line":"39.8","Second Line":"43.6"},{"date":"20120118","First Line":"43.2","Second Line":"45.0"},{"date":"20120119","First Line":"26.3","Second Line":"47.3"},{"date":"20120120","First Line":"32.8","Second Line":"51.4"},{"date":"20120121","First Line":"27.4","Second Line":"53.7"},{"date":"20120122","First Line":"25.0","Second Line":"48.3"},{"date":"20120123","First Line":"39.4","Second Line":"52.9"},{"date":"20120124","First Line":"48.7","Second Line":"49.1"},{"date":"20120125","First Line":"43.0","Second Line":"52.1"},{"date":"20120126","First Line":"37.1","Second Line":"53.6"},{"date":"20120127","First Line":"48.2","Second Line":"50.4"},{"date":"20120128","First Line":"43.7","Second Line":"50.3"},{"date":"20120129","First Line":"40.1","Second Line":"53.8"},{"date":"20120130","First Line":"38.0","Second Line":"51.9"},{"date":"20120131","First Line":"43.5","Second Line":"50.0"},{"date":"20120201","First Line":"50.4","Second Line":"50.0"},{"date":"20120202","First Line":"45.8","Second Line":"51.3"},{"date":"20120203","First Line":"37.5","Second Line":"51.5"},{"date":"20120204","First Line":"40.8","Second Line":"52.0"},{"date":"20120205","First Line":"36.5","Second Line":"53.8"},{"date":"20120206","First Line":"39.1","Second Line":"54.6"},{"date":"20120207","First Line":"43.2","Second Line":"54.3"},{"date":"20120208","First Line":"36.5","Second Line":"51.9"},{"date":"20120209","First Line":"36.5","Second Line":"53.8"},{"date":"20120210","First Line":"38.3","Second Line":"53.9"},{"date":"20120211","First Line":"36.9","Second Line":"52.3"},{"date":"20120212","First Line":"29.7","Second Line":"50.1"},{"date":"20120213","First Line":"33.1","Second Line":"49.5"},{"date":"20120214","First Line":"39.6","Second Line":"48.6"},{"date":"20120215","First Line":"42.3","Second Line":"49.9"},{"date":"20120216","First Line":"39.7","Second Line":"52.4"},{"date":"20120217","First Line":"46.0","Second Line":"49.9"},{"date":"20120218","First Line":"41.2","Second Line":"51.6"},{"date":"20120219","First Line":"39.8","Second Line":"47.8"},{"date":"20120220","First Line":"38.1","Second Line":"48.7"},{"date":"20120221","First Line":"37.1","Second Line":"49.7"},{"date":"20120222","First Line":"45.5","Second Line":"53.4"},{"date":"20120223","First Line":"50.6","Second Line":"54.1"},{"date":"20120224","First Line":"42.7","Second Line":"55.9"},{"date":"20120225","First Line":"42.6","Second Line":"51.7"},{"date":"20120226","First Line":"36.9","Second Line":"47.7"},{"date":"20120227","First Line":"40.9","Second Line":"45.4"},{"date":"20120228","First Line":"45.9","Second Line":"47.0"},{"date":"20120229","First Line":"40.7","Second Line":"49.8"},{"date":"20120301","First Line":"41.3","Second Line":"48.9"},{"date":"20120302","First Line":"36.8","Second Line":"48.1"},{"date":"20120303","First Line":"47.6","Second Line":"50.7"},{"date":"20120304","First Line":"44.2","Second Line":"55.0"},{"date":"20120305","First Line":"38.5","Second Line":"48.8"},{"date":"20120306","First Line":"32.9","Second Line":"48.4"},{"date":"20120307","First Line":"43.3","Second Line":"49.9"},{"date":"20120308","First Line":"51.2","Second Line":"49.2"},{"date":"20120309","First Line":"47.8","Second Line":"51.7"},{"date":"20120310","First Line":"37.2","Second Line":"49.3"},{"date":"20120311","First Line":"42.9","Second Line":"50.0"},{"date":"20120312","First Line":"48.8","Second Line":"48.6"},{"date":"20120313","First Line":"52.6","Second Line":"53.9"},{"date":"20120314","First Line":"60.5","Second Line":"55.2"},{"date":"20120315","First Line":"47.2","Second Line":"55.9"},{"date":"20120316","First Line":"44.7","Second Line":"54.6"},{"date":"20120317","First Line":"48.2","Second Line":"48.2"},{"date":"20120318","First Line":"48.2","Second Line":"47.1"},{"date":"20120319","First Line":"53.1","Second Line":"45.8"},{"date":"20120320","First Line":"57.8","Second Line":"49.7"},{"date":"20120321","First Line":"57.5","Second Line":"51.4"},{"date":"20120322","First Line":"57.3","Second Line":"51.4"},{"date":"20120323","First Line":"61.7","Second Line":"48.4"},{"date":"20120324","First Line":"55.8","Second Line":"49.0"},{"date":"20120325","First Line":"48.4","Second Line":"46.4"},{"date":"20120326","First Line":"49.8","Second Line":"49.7"},{"date":"20120327","First Line":"39.6","Second Line":"54.1"},{"date":"20120328","First Line":"49.7","Second Line":"54.6"},{"date":"20120329","First Line":"56.8","Second Line":"52.3"},{"date":"20120330","First Line":"46.5","Second Line":"54.5"},{"date":"20120331","First Line":"42.2","Second Line":"56.2"},{"date":"20120401","First Line":"45.3","Second Line":"51.1"},{"date":"20120402","First Line":"48.1","Second Line":"50.5"},{"date":"20120403","First Line":"51.2","Second Line":"52.2"},{"date":"20120404","First Line":"61.0","Second Line":"50.6"},{"date":"20120405","First Line":"50.7","Second Line":"47.9"},{"date":"20120406","First Line":"48.0","Second Line":"47.4"},{"date":"20120407","First Line":"51.1","Second Line":"49.4"},{"date":"20120408","First Line":"55.7","Second Line":"50.0"},{"date":"20120409","First Line":"58.3","Second Line":"51.3"},{"date":"20120410","First Line":"55.0","Second Line":"53.8"},{"date":"20120411","First Line":"49.0","Second Line":"52.9"},{"date":"20120412","First Line":"51.7","Second Line":"53.9"},{"date":"20120413","First Line":"53.1","Second Line":"50.2"},{"date":"20120414","First Line":"55.2","Second Line":"50.9"},{"date":"20120415","First Line":"62.3","Second Line":"51.5"},{"date":"20120416","First Line":"62.9","Second Line":"51.9"},{"date":"20120417","First Line":"69.3","Second Line":"53.2"},{"date":"20120418","First Line":"59.0","Second Line":"53.0"},{"date":"20120419","First Line":"54.1","Second Line":"55.1"},{"date":"20120420","First Line":"56.5","Second Line":"55.8"},{"date":"20120421","First Line":"58.2","Second Line":"58.0"},{"date":"20120422","First Line":"52.4","Second Line":"52.8"},{"date":"20120423","First Line":"51.6","Second Line":"55.1"},{"date":"20120424","First Line":"49.3","Second Line":"57.9"},{"date":"20120425","First Line":"52.5","Second Line":"57.5"},{"date":"20120426","First Line":"50.5","Second Line":"55.3"},{"date":"20120427","First Line":"51.9","Second Line":"53.5"},{"date":"20120428","First Line":"47.4","Second Line":"54.7"},{"date":"20120429","First Line":"54.1","Second Line":"54.0"},{"date":"20120430","First Line":"51.9","Second Line":"53.4"},{"date":"20120501","First Line":"57.4","Second Line":"52.7"},{"date":"20120502","First Line":"53.7","Second Line":"50.7"},{"date":"20120503","First Line":"53.1","Second Line":"52.6"},{"date":"20120504","First Line":"57.2","Second Line":"53.4"},{"date":"20120505","First Line":"57.0","Second Line":"53.1"},{"date":"20120506","First Line":"56.6","Second Line":"56.5"},{"date":"20120507","First Line":"54.6","Second Line":"55.3"},{"date":"20120508","First Line":"57.9","Second Line":"52.0"},{"date":"20120509","First Line":"59.2","Second Line":"52.4"},{"date":"20120510","First Line":"61.1","Second Line":"53.4"},{"date":"20120511","First Line":"59.7","Second Line":"53.1"},{"date":"20120512","First Line":"64.1","Second Line":"49.9"},{"date":"20120513","First Line":"65.3","Second Line":"52.0"},{"date":"20120514","First Line":"64.2","Second Line":"56.0"},{"date":"20120515","First Line":"62.0","Second Line":"53.0"},{"date":"20120516","First Line":"63.8","Second Line":"51.0"},{"date":"20120517","First Line":"64.5","Second Line":"51.4"},{"date":"20120518","First Line":"61.0","Second Line":"52.2"},{"date":"20120519","First Line":"62.6","Second Line":"52.4"},{"date":"20120520","First Line":"66.2","Second Line":"54.5"},{"date":"20120521","First Line":"62.7","Second Line":"52.8"},{"date":"20120522","First Line":"63.7","Second Line":"53.9"},{"date":"20120523","First Line":"66.4","Second Line":"56.5"},{"date":"20120524","First Line":"64.5","Second Line":"54.7"},{"date":"20120525","First Line":"65.4","Second Line":"52.5"},{"date":"20120526","First Line":"69.4","Second Line":"52.1"},{"date":"20120527","First Line":"71.9","Second Line":"52.2"},{"date":"20120528","First Line":"74.4","Second Line":"52.9"},{"date":"20120529","First Line":"75.9","Second Line":"52.1"},{"date":"20120530","First Line":"72.9","Second Line":"52.1"},{"date":"20120531","First Line":"72.5","Second Line":"53.3"},{"date":"20120601","First Line":"67.2","Second Line":"54.8"},{"date":"20120602","First Line":"68.3","Second Line":"54.0"},{"date":"20120603","First Line":"67.7","Second Line":"52.3"},{"date":"20120604","First Line":"61.9","Second Line":"55.3"},{"date":"20120605","First Line":"58.3","Second Line":"53.5"},{"date":"20120606","First Line":"61.7","Second Line":"54.1"},{"date":"20120607","First Line":"66.7","Second Line":"53.9"},{"date":"20120608","First Line":"68.7","Second Line":"54.4"},{"date":"20120609","First Line":"72.2","Second Line":"55.0"},{"date":"20120610","First Line":"72.6","Second Line":"60.0"},{"date":"20120611","First Line":"69.2","Second Line":"57.2"},{"date":"20120612","First Line":"66.9","Second Line":"55.1"},{"date":"20120613","First Line":"66.7","Second Line":"53.3"},{"date":"20120614","First Line":"67.7","Second Line":"53.4"},{"date":"20120615","First Line":"68.5","Second Line":"54.6"},{"date":"20120616","First Line":"67.5","Second Line":"57.0"},{"date":"20120617","First Line":"64.2","Second Line":"55.6"},{"date":"20120618","First Line":"61.7","Second Line":"52.5"},{"date":"20120619","First Line":"66.4","Second Line":"53.9"},{"date":"20120620","First Line":"77.9","Second Line":"55.3"},{"date":"20120621","First Line":"88.3","Second Line":"53.3"},{"date":"20120622","First Line":"82.2","Second Line":"54.1"},{"date":"20120623","First Line":"77.0","Second Line":"55.2"},{"date":"20120624","First Line":"75.4","Second Line":"55.8"},{"date":"20120625","First Line":"70.9","Second Line":"56.8"},{"date":"20120626","First Line":"65.9","Second Line":"57.5"},{"date":"20120627","First Line":"73.5","Second Line":"57.7"},{"date":"20120628","First Line":"77.4","Second Line":"56.6"},{"date":"20120629","First Line":"79.6","Second Line":"56.4"},{"date":"20120630","First Line":"84.2","Second Line":"58.4"},{"date":"20120701","First Line":"81.8","Second Line":"58.8"},{"date":"20120702","First Line":"82.5","Second Line":"56.4"},{"date":"20120703","First Line":"80.2","Second Line":"56.5"},{"date":"20120704","First Line":"77.8","Second Line":"55.8"},{"date":"20120705","First Line":"86.1","Second Line":"54.8"},{"date":"20120706","First Line":"79.9","Second Line":"54.9"},{"date":"20120707","First Line":"83.5","Second Line":"54.7"},{"date":"20120708","First Line":"81.5","Second Line":"52.8"},{"date":"20120709","First Line":"77.8","Second Line":"53.7"},{"date":"20120710","First Line":"76.1","Second Line":"53.1"},{"date":"20120711","First Line":"76.3","Second Line":"52.7"},{"date":"20120712","First Line":"75.8","Second Line":"52.0"},{"date":"20120713","First Line":"77.2","Second Line":"53.4"},{"date":"20120714","First Line":"79.3","Second Line":"54.0"},{"date":"20120715","First Line":"78.9","Second Line":"54.0"},{"date":"20120716","First Line":"79.6","Second Line":"54.5"},{"date":"20120717","First Line":"83.3","Second Line":"56.7"},{"date":"20120718","First Line":"84.3","Second Line":"57.5"},{"date":"20120719","First Line":"75.1","Second Line":"57.1"},{"date":"20120720","First Line":"68.4","Second Line":"58.1"},{"date":"20120721","First Line":"68.4","Second Line":"57.6"},{"date":"20120722","First Line":"72.2","Second Line":"56.0"},{"date":"20120723","First Line":"75.6","Second Line":"56.6"},{"date":"20120724","First Line":"82.6","Second Line":"57.8"},{"date":"20120725","First Line":"78.4","Second Line":"57.5"},{"date":"20120726","First Line":"77.0","Second Line":"56.4"},{"date":"20120727","First Line":"79.4","Second Line":"55.3"},{"date":"20120728","First Line":"77.4","Second Line":"55.0"},{"date":"20120729","First Line":"72.5","Second Line":"55.6"},{"date":"20120730","First Line":"72.9","Second Line":"55.6"},{"date":"20120731","First Line":"73.6","Second Line":"55.9"},{"date":"20120801","First Line":"75.0","Second Line":"55.4"},{"date":"20120802","First Line":"77.7","Second Line":"54.4"},{"date":"20120803","First Line":"79.7","Second Line":"53.7"},{"date":"20120804","First Line":"79.6","Second Line":"54.1"},{"date":"20120805","First Line":"81.5","Second Line":"57.8"},{"date":"20120806","First Line":"80.0","Second Line":"58.2"},{"date":"20120807","First Line":"75.7","Second Line":"58.0"},{"date":"20120808","First Line":"77.8","Second Line":"57.0"},{"date":"20120809","First Line":"78.6","Second Line":"55.0"},{"date":"20120810","First Line":"77.8","Second Line":"54.8"},{"date":"20120811","First Line":"78.5","Second Line":"53.0"},{"date":"20120812","First Line":"78.8","Second Line":"52.5"},{"date":"20120813","First Line":"78.6","Second Line":"53.3"},{"date":"20120814","First Line":"76.8","Second Line":"53.9"},{"date":"20120815","First Line":"76.7","Second Line":"56.2"},{"date":"20120816","First Line":"75.9","Second Line":"57.1"},{"date":"20120817","First Line":"77.6","Second Line":"55.3"},{"date":"20120818","First Line":"72.6","Second Line":"56.2"},{"date":"20120819","First Line":"70.4","Second Line":"54.3"},{"date":"20120820","First Line":"71.8","Second Line":"53.1"},{"date":"20120821","First Line":"73.6","Second Line":"53.4"},{"date":"20120822","First Line":"74.7","Second Line":"54.5"},{"date":"20120823","First Line":"74.6","Second Line":"55.7"},{"date":"20120824","First Line":"76.0","Second Line":"54.8"},{"date":"20120825","First Line":"76.2","Second Line":"53.8"},{"date":"20120826","First Line":"73.4","Second Line":"56.5"},{"date":"20120827","First Line":"74.6","Second Line":"58.3"},{"date":"20120828","First Line":"79.4","Second Line":"58.7"},{"date":"20120829","First Line":"74.7","Second Line":"57.5"},{"date":"20120830","First Line":"73.5","Second Line":"55.9"},{"date":"20120831","First Line":"77.9","Second Line":"55.4"},{"date":"20120901","First Line":"80.7","Second Line":"55.7"},{"date":"20120902","First Line":"75.1","Second Line":"53.1"},{"date":"20120903","First Line":"73.5","Second Line":"53.5"},{"date":"20120904","First Line":"73.5","Second Line":"52.5"},{"date":"20120905","First Line":"77.7","Second Line":"54.5"},{"date":"20120906","First Line":"74.2","Second Line":"56.3"},{"date":"20120907","First Line":"76.0","Second Line":"56.4"},{"date":"20120908","First Line":"77.1","Second Line":"56.5"},{"date":"20120909","First Line":"69.7","Second Line":"56.4"},{"date":"20120910","First Line":"67.8","Second Line":"55.4"},{"date":"20120911","First Line":"64.0","Second Line":"56.2"},{"date":"20120912","First Line":"68.1","Second Line":"55.7"},{"date":"20120913","First Line":"69.3","Second Line":"54.3"},{"date":"20120914","First Line":"70.0","Second Line":"55.2"},{"date":"20120915","First Line":"69.3","Second Line":"54.3"},{"date":"20120916","First Line":"66.3","Second Line":"52.9"},{"date":"20120917","First Line":"67.0","Second Line":"54.8"},{"date":"20120918","First Line":"72.8","Second Line":"54.8"},{"date":"20120919","First Line":"67.2","Second Line":"56.8"},{"date":"20120920","First Line":"62.1","Second Line":"55.4"},{"date":"20120921","First Line":"64.0","Second Line":"55.8"},{"date":"20120922","First Line":"65.5","Second Line":"55.9"},{"date":"20120923","First Line":"65.7","Second Line":"52.8"},{"date":"20120924","First Line":"60.4","Second Line":"54.5"},{"date":"20120925","First Line":"63.2","Second Line":"53.3"},{"date":"20120926","First Line":"68.5","Second Line":"53.6"},{"date":"20120927","First Line":"69.2","Second Line":"52.1"},{"date":"20120928","First Line":"68.7","Second Line":"52.6"},{"date":"20120929","First Line":"62.5","Second Line":"53.9"},{"date":"20120930","First Line":"62.3","Second Line":"55.1"}];

var margin = {top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 30, left: 50},
    width = 960 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

var parseDate = d3.time.format("%Y%m%d").parse;

var x = d3.time.scale()
    .range([0, width]);

var y = d3.scale.linear()
    .range([height, 0]);

var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(x)
    .orient("bottom");

var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(y)
    .orient("left");

var line = d3.svg.area()
    .interpolate("basis")
    .x(function(d) { return x(d.date); })
    .y(function(d) { return y(Math.min(d["First Line"], d["Second Line"])); });

var area = d3.svg.area()
    .interpolate("basis")
    .x(function(d) { return x(d.date); })
    .y1(function(d) { return y(d["First Line"]); });

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");
    
data.forEach(function(d) {
    d.date = parseDate(d.date);
    d["First Line"]= +d["First Line"];
    d["Second Line"] = +d["Second Line"];
});

x.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d.date; }));

y.domain([
  d3.min(data, function(d) { return Math.min(d["First Line"], d["Second Line"]); }),
  d3.max(data, function(d) { return Math.max(d["First Line"], d["Second Line"]); })
]);

svg.datum(data);

svg.append("clipPath")
  .attr("id", "clip-above")
  .append("path")
  .attr("d", area.y0(height));

svg.append("clipPath")
  .attr("id", "clip-below")
  .append("path")
  .attr("d", area.y0(0));

svg.append("path")
  .attr("class", "area below")
  .attr("clip-path", "url(#clip-below)")
  .attr("d", area.y0(function(d) { return y(d["Second Line"]); }));

svg.append("path")
  .attr("class", "area above")
  .attr("clip-path", "url(#clip-above)")
  .attr("d", area);

svg.append("path")
  .attr("class", "line")
  .attr("d", line.y0(height));

svg.append("g")
  .attr("class", "x axis")
  .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
  .call(xAxis);

svg.append("g")
  .attr("class", "y axis")
  .call(yAxis)
  .append("text")
  .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
  .attr("y", 6)
  .attr("dy", ".71em")
  .style("text-anchor", "end")
  .text("Temperature (ºF)");
```

```css
body {
  font: 10px sans-serif;
}

.axis path,
.axis line {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #000;
  shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}

.x.axis path {
  /*display: none;*/
}

.area.below {
  fill: rgb(252,141,89);
  stroke: #000;
  stroke-width: 1px;
}

.area.above {
  fill: rgb(145,207,96);
  stroke: #000;
  stroke-width: 1px;
}

.line {
  fill: #ccc;
  stroke: #000;
  stroke-width: 0.5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
<div id="chart"></div>
```